# Determine the values of $k$ for which the given line and the plane are parallel

Tags: vector-spaces

Determine the values of $k$ for which the line $\frac{x}{2}=ky=k-z$ and the plane $(2k-1)x-ky+z=5+k$ are parallel.

I got the answer $k=1$ by equating the dot product of the normal to the plane and the direction vector of the line to zero.

However, in the answer sheet, the answer is $k=0$ and $k=1$.

My question is how do I get the answer $k=0$?

Answer (score 0):

When you solve, it involves multiplying both sides to get a quadratic in k, So we automatically neglect k=0 as a solution. You will have to put the value of k=0 and check seperately to get complete solution